# Android Firebase: Overwrite value instead of create an new entry

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling with a project I want to continue to develop that I found on GitHub. It is just for self-education purposes, because I want to work more efficient with the firebase. Here is the project and the whole code of it. -> [Project](https://github.com/uurcan/TypingTest/)

Now to my problem. After you finish the game, the app is creating a new entry in the firebase every time. These lines are in the *SingeWordActivity.class* and they are creating the output for the firebase:

```
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_SCORE);
    String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
    User user = new User(id, getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.USER_NICK, getString(R.string.OK)),
            numberOfLetters / 5, numberOfLetters, true);
    if (id != null) {
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user);
    }
}
```

The *Constants* are just linked in a different class, seeing below:

```
public class Constants {
public static final int BANNER_SCREEN_TIMEOUT = 3000;
public static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 1500;
public static final String PREF_FIRST_TIME = "isFirstTime";
public static final String USER_NICK = "userNick";
public static final String USER_PREFERENCE = "userPref";
public static final String USER_SCORE = "score-list";
public static final String IS_FIRST_LOGIN = "isFirst";
public static final String GAME_TYPE = "game_type";
public static final String PARAGRAPH = "paragraph";
public static final String SINGLE_WORD = "single_word";


public static int MILLIS_IN_FUTURE = 60000;
public static final int COUNTDOWN_INTERVAL = 1000;
```

}

This is how it looks like in the firebase at the end:

[image: View in the firebase]

Is there a way that after the Activity, every value (**userScore,singelWord,userLetterCount**) in the firebase gets updated and these values are linked with the "**userName**"?

So it is not possible the have duplicate **userNames** in the firebase?

[image: Is-state, two entries for the same user]

-----UPDATE:------

To update the Firebase only if (score) value is greater than the existing one you have to change the firebase settings. Like in the following:

[firebase code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYwxw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `push()` on Firebase Realtime Database, it generates a new unique location and key. So this line, generates a new key:

```
String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
```

If you want to update an existing node, you need to know the id of that node, instead of generating a new unique one. For example, if you want to update Peter's score, you can use a query to find the existing node(s) for Peter:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_SCORE);
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo("Peter")
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot resultsSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: resultsSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      User user = new User(id, getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.USER_NICK, getString(R.string.OK)),
        numberOfLetters / 5, numberOfLetters, true);
      userSnapshot.getReference().setValue(user);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

You'll note in the above that I said "node(s)" as there may be multiple child nodes where `userName` is `Peter`. If that is a situation you want to prevent, you can consider using the user name as the ID for the nodes. If Peter's score is stored under `/score-list/Peter`, there can always only be one score - as each node path is guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `push`, it generates a new unique key. So if you want to update the values based on `userName`, you can do it like this:

```
String userName = getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.USER_NICK, getString(R.string.OK))

User user = new User(userName, numberOfLetters / 5, numberOfLetters, true);
databaseReference.child(userName).setValue(user);
```